# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

i have a javascript file (generated dynamically from php with javascript headers).
Now this code results in error, i tried to debug for quite some time without a clue:

**Error:** SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

```
document.write('$(function() '+
   '{ $("#verify").click(function() '+
   '{var order = ""; '+
   '$(".captchaimage").each(function() '+
   '{order += "ggggg"+ $(this).attr("name");}) '+
   'console.log(order); '+
   '$.ajax({ '+
   'url: "http://healtheworld.com/own/json.php?var=" + order.substring(5), '+
   'dataType: "text", '+
   'cache: false, '+
   'success: function(data){console.log(data);} }); '+
   '}); '+
   '});');
```

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: Why would you need this? Writing a function to a page is horrible. Conditionally include as a variable it if required.

Comment: Have you checked the result that is inserted to the HTML file? What happens when you extract this code and try to run it directly?

Comment: try debug with Firebug / where this error cause?

Comment: @TusharGupta You must be horrible at indenting and editing then.

Comment: @aurun i do this because i want to write a captcha api to compete against recaptcha from google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ; is missing here:

```
'{order += "ggggg"+ $(this).attr("name");}) '+
```

You need it at the end:

```
'{order += "ggggg"+ $(this).attr("name");}) ; '+
```

But it is really not nice coding style ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? If PHP generates it, put it inside a `<script></script>`, not like this.

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
   $("#verify").click(function() {
      var order = "";
   $(".captchaimage").each(function(){
      order += "ggggg"+ $(this).attr("name");
   }) 
   console.log(order); 
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://healtheworld.com/own/json.php?var=" + order.substring(5), 
      dataType: "text", 
      cache: false, 
      success: function(data){console.log(data);} }); 
   }); 
});
</script>
```